# How to access UserManager<IdentityUser> instance from WebApplication instance app in program.cs in asp.net core 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to access UserManager instance to seed IdentityUser data, I am doing in program.cs file
Below is given code snippet

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<MyIdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapControllers();

app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller = Home}/{action = Index}/{Id?}"
    );
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
app.MapRazorPages();

var scopeFactory = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<MyIdentityUser>>();

SeedInitialData.SeedData(roleManager, userManager);

app.Run();
```

and I receive this exception

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

Please help me, how to find this issue. regards

I read many articles, and I tried some of them, none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a simple demo to show how to seed data to identity in asp.net core, You can refer to it.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        //.........

        builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        //........
        app.UseAuthorization();

        using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            //Resolve ASP .NET Core Identity with DI help
            var userManager = (UserManager<IdentityUser>)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(UserManager<IdentityUser>));
            var roleManager = (RoleManager<IdentityRole>)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(RoleManager<IdentityRole>));
            // do you things here

            MyIdentityDataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);
        }

       //........

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

**MyIdentityDataInitializer class**

```
public static  class MyIdentityDataInitializer
    {
        public static void SeedData(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            SeedRoles(roleManager);
            SeedUsers(userManager);
        }

        public static void SeedUsers(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            if (userManager.FindByNameAsync("user1").Result == null)
            {
                IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser();
                user.UserName = "user1";
                user.Email = "user1@localhost";               
                IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Password123!!!").Result;

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,
                                        "NormalUser").Wait();
                }
            }


            if (userManager.FindByNameAsync("user2").Result == null)
            {
                IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser();
                user.UserName = "user2";
                user.Email = "user2@localhost";
                IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Password123!!!").Result;

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,
                                        "Administrator").Wait();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void SeedRoles(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            if (!roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("NormalUser").Result)
            {
                IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "NormalUser";
                
                IdentityResult roleResult = roleManager.CreateAsync(role).Result;
            }


            if (!roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Administrator").Result)
            {
                IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "Administrator";
               
                IdentityResult roleResult = roleManager.CreateAsync(role).Result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when I run my project, The data will be seeded successfully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for your time and support, my problem is solved, but I need to get more information regarding identity configuration and program.cs class

Comment: This is a simple demo, You can just  refer to the `using()` code. Now can you seed data successfully?

Comment: Why there is not main method in .net 7 asp.net core?

Comment: You can refer to this [article](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/blog/2021/11/asp-net-core-identity-adddefaultidentity-vs-addidentity/) to learn the difference , When you create your project, you can select `Do not use top-level statements`, Then you will have main method in your .net 7 project.

Comment: Identity service configuration as your have described is different with my case. In your case 
`builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true) .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
` 
in my case 
`builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<MyIdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true) .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>(); 
` 
What is difference between Services.AddIdentity vs Services.AddDefaultIdentity

Comment: Roles is the only real difference between the two. AddDefaultIdentity : removes roles, use when you do not need roles, AddIdentity : use when you need roles. Here i need to pass RoleManager to MyIdentityDataInitializer class, So i use AddIdentity instead of AddDefaultIdentity here.  AddDefaultIdentity is similar to AddIdentity + AddDefaultTokens + AddDefaultUI. AddDefaultIdentity is just syntatic sugar for the old code

Comment: so nice of your and really thankful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just so everyone is clear. The error is caused because the project template for "Blazer Server with Identity" uses the AddDefaultIdentity service:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<MyIdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

Which for some reason does not work with:

```cs
//Resolve ASP .NET Core Identity with DI help
var userManager = (UserManager<IdentityUser>)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(UserManager<IdentityUser>));
var roleManager = (RoleManager<IdentityRole>)scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(RoleManager<IdentityRole>));
```

So you need to change to:

```cs
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```